# What flowers can attract hummingbird?

Tags: flowers, hummingbirds

My neighbor has a tall trumpet vine, and many hummingbirds live around this plant. I wonder if I could plant some shade flowers also feed hummingbirds. Could you recommend some shade flowers that go well under the following conditions?

1. USDA zone 10a
2. In-ground & drought tolerant
3. 3-4 hours sunlight
4. Goes well with roses

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Florida Native Plant Society](https://www.fnps.org/plant/lobelia-cardinalis), Cardinal Flower (*Lobelia cardinalis*) is native to zone 9b (according to the USDA, it's native to Polk County, which is zone 10a). If you're adventurous, you could try it in your 10a climate. If you're in the US, it will be a very inexpensive plant because it is very easy to propagate. Cardinal Flower is a true hummingbird magnet - mine get visited at least twice a day while they're in bloom. They're also long-bloomers. More information [here](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/lobelia-cardinalis/).